# DNS issues after KB3200970 and KB3202790 updates installed

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, troubleshooting

I have notices the issues after I let run Windows it updates a week ago. O The issue is illustrated [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKwRY.jpg). What's happening is that when I open a link (or a new tab, etc), it's very likely the first request will give me the Chrome error page for no DNS entry for the URL, however on a refresh it resolves it just fine.

If there are other domains being requested on the page (e.g. as an embedded image), they have a high chance of failing also, leading to many occasions where the page finally retrieved is a plain white page with text. One more refresh and most issues are completely gone.

It appears to be occurring system-wide, just the only way I can easily "see" it is via Chrome or Firefox. The issue does not appear to be present at all on my phone (while under Wi-fi). I have no idea what's causing this suddenly - I've run several malware scans and nothing has fixed it, I've tried using both Google's public DNS as well as OpenDNS and neither has fixed it (and in the former case I often get the DNS errors when searching on Google).

Any help in resolving this would be so tremendously appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can try to use Wireshark (both on client and on server) to check what's happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were able to reproduce the issue on another PC? It seems like a networking issue.

First try to reset IP and Winsock settings and restart the PC

```
netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
netsh winsock reset
```

If problem persists, try to update / rollback / reinstall your NIC drivers.